# Minimize total distance using k links among n nodes

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I came up with the following problem that I do not know the solutions to nor can I find the 'lookup' term to investigate further.

Say we have N ordered nodes (n_1,n_2....n_N) each with a fixed distance of 1 between them. So dist(n_1,n_N) = N-1. Now we are are allowed to connect any two nodes, thus effectively reducing their distance to 1. Assume we can have k such connections.

The problem is : how do we choose which nodes to connect to minimize the total distance between any two nodes ?

Is this problem a known variant of some well-studied problem ? Does an efficient solution exist for this (or a variant where we only want to minimize the max distance between any two nodes)

Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between minimizing "total distance between any two nodes" and minimizing "the max distance between any two nodes"?

Comment: total distance means sum of distances between all pairs of nodes. max distance is the largest distance from the set of all distances between pairs of nodes. I am not sure but they don't seem equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in "[On the sum of all distances in a graph or digraph](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190080102/abstract)". That paper refers to your "total distance" as the "transmission" of a graph. Your "max distance" is generally called the "diameter" of a graph. It discusses the two, proves some properties of a graph's transmission, and shows that the transmission and diameter are independent of one another.

Naively, you've got n-choose-k options to try. That's pretty bad if n and k are large. Not too bad if one of them is small.

There is work on doing better than that. [This Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76825/178) asks about reducing the mean distance between vertices, which is proportional to the transmission of the graph. There are two answers, neither of which I can vouch for. It also refers to [a paper](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~awm/papers/APPROX09-NoC.pdf) that directly addresses this question.

Minimizing the diameter of a graph is dealt with in [this paper](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/62215).

You might consider addressing this question to the Math stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information. I will try to read some of the resources and ask further if needed on Math Exchange.